# In flutter, how to make a button clickable only if there is some value in Text form field?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am creating a flutter application where users are allowed to post some data (perform CRUD operations). But the issue is that even if some user doesn't put any value in the text form field (i.e text form is empty) and he clicks on Post button, a new field is created in the firebase. I want that the user may click the Post button only if there is some value in the Text field. I tried `autovalidateMode` but it couldn't solve the problem. Although it shows the error, but still the button is clicked and blank post is created. How can I make that button clickable only if there is some data?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ButtonFile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonFileState createState() => _ButtonFileState();
}

class _ButtonFileState extends State<ButtonFile> {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String newPost;


  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('form'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(children: [
          Form(
            key: _formKey,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            child: TextFormField(
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              validator: (_val) {
                if (_val.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter something';
                }
                return null;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Post'),
              // onChanged: (String post) {
              //   getNewPost(post);
              onChanged: (_val) {
                newPost = _val;
              },
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                db.collection('Posts').add({'post': newPost});
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Post'))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if-else` logic to check whether there is a value when your button is clicked.

```
 onPressed: () {
      if(newPost!=""){
          db.collection('Posts').add({'post': newPost});
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Although your answer didn't work but still thanks, because your answer gave me the idea and I modified it in the following code and it worked; 
onPressed: () {
                  if (newPost.isNotEmpty) {
                    db.collection('Posts').add({'post': newPost});
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },

Comment: I forgot to mention this..if you declare newPost as this `String newPost = "";`, the answer given will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: (newPost != null && newPost.isNotEmpty) 
       ? () {
                db.collection('Posts').add({'post': newPost});
                Navigator.pop(context);
              } 
       : null,
   child: Text('Post'))
```

Comment: But this disables the button whether the user puts some data value in text field or not. Button is not clickable

Comment: You said how to make a button clickable only if there is some value in Text form field?

so that was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. So what we have here is have an extra state variable named `_validate`.
2. When `validator()` in the form is run, it will set the value of `_validate` to true if the value supplied to the text area is empty.
3. When the user presses the button, there is an `if else` statement which will check the value of `_validate` state variable and accordingly will post a document in firebase.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ButtonFile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonFileState createState() => _ButtonFileState();
}

class _ButtonFileState extends State<ButtonFile> {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String newPost;

  bool _validate = false;


  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('form'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(children: [
          Form(
            key: _formKey,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            child: TextFormField(
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              validator: (_val) {
                if (_val.isEmpty) {

                  setState(() {
                    _validate = true;                    
                  });

                  return 'Please enter something';
                }
                return null;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Post'),
              // onChanged: (String post) {
              //   getNewPost(post);
              onChanged: (_val) {
                newPost = _val;
              },
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {

                if (_validate) {
                  // error you would like to display
                  // might be a snackbar
                } else {
                  db.collection('Posts').add({'post': newPost});
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                } 

              },
              child: Text('Post'))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but now the page is not working anymore. Following error is showing in debug console, setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.